# Replace values in one column with another column values on conditions

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a df that looks like this

```
ID num1       children num2
34 self       1        1
23 none       2        0
85 dependents 3        2
```

I'd like to replace the values in `num2` with the values from `children` only if `num1` = 'dependents'. I've tried a handful of things including `mask` but haven't been able to get it to work

```
mask = (df['num1'] == 2)
df['num1'][mask] = df['children']
```

ideally the output looks like this

```
ID num1       children num2
34 self       1        1
23 none       2        0
85 dependents 3        3
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Series.where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html) / [`Series.mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html)

```
cond = df['num1'].eq('dependents')
df['num2'] = df['num2'].mask(cond,df['children'])
#df['num2'] = df['children'].where(cond,df['num2'])
```

or [`DataFrame.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
df.loc[cond,'num2'] = df['children']
```

**Output**

```
   ID        num1  children  num2
0  34        self         1     1
1  23        none         2     0
2  85  dependents         3     3
```

**Detail**

```
print(cond)
0    False
1    False
2     True
Name: num1, dtype: bool
```

Comment: I'd have written the cond as `df['num1] == 'dependents'` is there an advantage of using df equality here @ansev? (specifically for usage in the `.loc` method.

Comment: it's really the same, I usually use `.eq ()` because it's more comfortable not to have to use parentheses when using logical operators like`|` or `&` to verify multiple conditions

Comment: for example `(df['a'].eq(1) & df['b'].ne(2))` vs `( (df['a'] ==1) & (df['b'] !=1) )`

Comment: Yeah I buy that! Thanks. Just made me wonder if there was some other nuance I didn't know about.